# How to show UTF8 character in PL/SQL developer by windows 10?

Tags: windows, oracle, utf-8, localization, plsqldeveloper

My problem is that my PL/SQL developer doesn't show UTF8 characters, instead it shows as squares.

1. I changed all "NLS_LANG" variable to 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8' in registry.
2. I added my language in region&language from control panel of windows.
3. In plsql developer "Tools>preferences>options>Unicode enabled" is checked.

(windows 10 & oracle 11g & plsql developer 9).

what else I missed?

Comment: Try another font. For example "Lucida console", "Consolas".

Comment: thanks @daniel-sęk, but it doesn't work.

Comment: setting `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8` worked for me